# Prebid Server Deployment: Cache Duration and Request Limits

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

I'm preparing to deploy my own Prebid Server and have a few queries prior to initiating the process:

1. Can anyone provide details on the maximum duration for holding a bid in the cache?
2. What is the maximum limit of bid requests that can be stored in the cache simultaneously?
3. Is the primary functionality of the Prebid Server via "GET" requests or "POST" requests?

(if that's important I'm planning on the method "**Server-Side via SSAI Server, Ad Server First")**

I appreciate your assistance in advance.